# What WS-Security settings should I apply to connect to wsdl descripted SOAP service?

Tags: java, wsdl, cxf, webservice-client, ws-security

I've been given task to create java client for a specific web service that is described by following wsdl file:

```xml
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<wsdl:definitions xmlns:wsdl="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/" xmlns:msc="http://schemas.microsoft.com/ws/2005/12/wsdl/contract" xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap/" xmlns:soap12="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/wsdl/soap12/" xmlns:soapenc="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/encoding/" xmlns:tns="http://tempuri.org/" xmlns:wsa="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing" xmlns:wsa10="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" xmlns:wsam="http://www.w3.org/2007/05/addressing/metadata" xmlns:wsap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/08/addressing/policy" xmlns:wsaw="http://www.w3.org/2006/05/addressing/wsdl" xmlns:wsp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/policy" xmlns:wsu="http://docs.oasis-open.org/wss/2004/01/oasis-200401-wss-wssecurity-utility-1.0.xsd" xmlns:wsx="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2004/09/mex" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" name="Person" targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/">
  <wsp:Policy wsu:Id="WSHttpBinding_IPersonService_policy">
    <wsp:ExactlyOne>
      <wsp:All>
        <sp:TransportBinding xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
          <wsp:Policy>
            <sp:TransportToken>
              <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:HttpsToken RequireClientCertificate="false" />
              </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:TransportToken>
            <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
              <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:Basic256 />
              </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
            <sp:Layout>
              <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:Strict />
              </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:Layout>
            <sp:IncludeTimestamp />
          </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:TransportBinding>
        <sp:EndorsingSupportingTokens xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
          <wsp:Policy>
            <sp:SecureConversationToken sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
              <wsp:Policy>
                <sp:BootstrapPolicy>
                  <wsp:Policy>
                    <sp:SignedParts>
                      <sp:Body />
                      <sp:Header Name="To" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                      <sp:Header Name="From" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                      <sp:Header Name="FaultTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                      <sp:Header Name="ReplyTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                      <sp:Header Name="MessageID" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                      <sp:Header Name="RelatesTo" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                      <sp:Header Name="Action" Namespace="http://www.w3.org/2005/08/addressing" />
                    </sp:SignedParts>
                    <sp:EncryptedParts>
                      <sp:Body />
                    </sp:EncryptedParts>
                    <sp:TransportBinding>
                      <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:TransportToken>
                          <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:HttpsToken RequireClientCertificate="false" />
                          </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:TransportToken>
                        <sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                          <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Basic256 />
                          </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:AlgorithmSuite>
                        <sp:Layout>
                          <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:Strict />
                          </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:Layout>
                        <sp:IncludeTimestamp />
                      </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:TransportBinding>
                    <sp:SignedSupportingTokens>
                      <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:UsernameToken sp:IncludeToken="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy/IncludeToken/AlwaysToRecipient">
                          <wsp:Policy>
                            <sp:WssUsernameToken10 />
                          </wsp:Policy>
                        </sp:UsernameToken>
                      </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:SignedSupportingTokens>
                    <sp:Wss11>
                      <wsp:Policy />
                    </sp:Wss11>
                    <sp:Trust10>
                      <wsp:Policy>
                        <sp:MustSupportIssuedTokens />
                        <sp:RequireClientEntropy />
                        <sp:RequireServerEntropy />
                      </wsp:Policy>
                    </sp:Trust10>
                  </wsp:Policy>
                </sp:BootstrapPolicy>
              </wsp:Policy>
            </sp:SecureConversationToken>
          </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:EndorsingSupportingTokens>
        <sp:Wss11 xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
          <wsp:Policy />
        </sp:Wss11>
        <sp:Trust10 xmlns:sp="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/ws/2005/07/securitypolicy">
          <wsp:Policy>
            <sp:MustSupportIssuedTokens />
            <sp:RequireClientEntropy />
            <sp:RequireServerEntropy />
          </wsp:Policy>
        </sp:Trust10>
        <wsaw:UsingAddressing />
      </wsp:All>
    </wsp:ExactlyOne>
  </wsp:Policy>
  <wsdl:types>
    <xsd:schema targetNamespace="http://tempuri.org/Imports">
      <xsd:import schemaLocation="https://localhost:442/Services/Person.svc?xsd=xsd0" namespace="http://tempuri.org/" />
      <xsd:import schemaLocation="https://localhost:442/Services/Person.svc?xsd=xsd1" namespace="http://schemas.microsoft.com/2003/10/Serialization/" />
    </xsd:schema>
  </wsdl:types>
  <wsdl:message name="IPersonService_GetSomething_InputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetSomething" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:message name="IPersonService_GetSomething_OutputMessage">
    <wsdl:part name="parameters" element="tns:GetSomethingResponse" />
  </wsdl:message>
  <wsdl:portType name="IPersonService">
    <wsdl:operation name="GetSomething">
      <wsdl:input wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IPersonService/GetSomething" message="tns:IPersonService_GetSomething_InputMessage" />
      <wsdl:output wsaw:Action="http://tempuri.org/IPersonService/GetSomethingResponse" message="tns:IPersonService_GetSomething_OutputMessage" />
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:portType>
  <wsdl:binding name="WSHttpBinding_IPersonService" type="tns:IPersonService">
    <wsp:PolicyReference URI="#WSHttpBinding_IPersonService_policy" />
    <soap12:binding transport="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/http" />
    <wsdl:operation name="GetSomething">
      <soap12:operation soapAction="http://tempuri.org/IPersonService/GetSomething" style="document" />
      <wsdl:input>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:input>
      <wsdl:output>
        <soap12:body use="literal" />
      </wsdl:output>
    </wsdl:operation>
  </wsdl:binding>
  <wsdl:service name="Person">
    <wsdl:port name="WSHttpBinding_IPersonService" binding="tns:WSHttpBinding_IPersonService">
      <soap12:address location="https://localhost:442/Services/Person.svc" />
      <wsa10:EndpointReference>
        <wsa10:Address>https://localhost:442/Services/Person.svc</wsa10:Address>
      </wsa10:EndpointReference>
    </wsdl:port>
  </wsdl:service>
</wsdl:definitions>
```

I've created java client with Apache CXF's wsdl2java and in client invocation used `new AddressingFeature(true)`, because services are in HTTPS, like that:

```
Person p = new Person();
IPersonService iPersonService = p.getWSHttpBindingIPersonService(new AddressingFeature(true));
System.out.println(iPersonService.getSomething());
```

but I get following exception:

> org.apache.cxf.binding.soap.SoapFault: The message could not be processed. This is most likely because the action 'http://tempuri.org/IPersonService/GetSomething' is incorrect or because the message contains an invalid or expired security context token or because there is a mismatch between bindings. The security context token would be invalid if the service aborted the channel due to inactivity. To prevent the service from aborting idle sessions prematurely increase the Receive timeout on the service endpoint's binding.

So far, I've tried adding `ws-security.username` and `ws-security.password` like so, but it didn't work, I get the same exception:

```
((BindingProvider) iPersonService).getRequestContext() 
   .put("ws-security.username", "user"); 
((BindingProvider) iPersonService).getRequestContext() 
   .put("ws-security.password", "password");
```

So, most probably I didn't applied some kind of security settings. Can anybody describe what WS-Security settings should I apply for this specific wsdl?

Update:
Added xsd schemas: https://gist.github.com/the-lay/12c2dc5091c5dc783f00

Comment: As I can see, you trying to connect to .Net Web Service. In that case I recommend you to use [Glassfish Metro](https://metro.java.net/guide/user-guide.html), not CXF.

Comment: And please post xsd files, locates at `https://localhost:442/Services/Person.svc?xsd=xsd0` and `https://localhost:442/Services/Person.svc?xsd=xsd1`

Comment: @user1516873 Thanks, I'll look what I can do with Metro! Also, I've updated post and added link to xsd schemas.

Comment: @user1516873 I think I have the same problem with Metro - I still don't really understand what kind of authentication I must use and what special fields should I send. Can you help with this out, please?

Comment: Sorry, but in my opinion wsdl is not for human read. I see some policy attached to endpoint, but what exactly policy applied and what exactly you should set I can't say. But I cat put a bounty.

Comment: Maybe check if the username and password you provide are correct - maybe the password should be passed in some hashed way?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problems were following:

- I didn't realise that if I don't use `cxf-rt-ws-policy` dependency then the policy settings of WSDL are being silently ignored. To solve this, I've added this to my `pom.xml` (or you can add the whole bundle - `cxf-bundle` package) and starting from there I've got another exception, but that was the progress anyway.
- After that I've got exception that "No Username provided", even though I had it in my `cxf.xml`. The problem was that I have used wrong `jaxws:client` name attribute. I've used the service name, but you must use the port name (which you can find in the end of the wsdl file) and you also have to use `createdFromAPI` attribute for that client. So, in the end it should look like this:

```xml
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
       xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
       xmlns:jaxws="http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws" xmlns:cxf="http://cxf.apache.org/core"
       xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
   http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-2.0.xsd
   http://cxf.apache.org/jaxws
   http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/jaxws.xsd http://cxf.apache.org/core http://cxf.apache.org/schemas/core.xsd">

    <cxf:bus> <!-- it's not mandatory, just easier with this -->
        <cxf:features>
            <cxf:logging/>
        </cxf:features>
    </cxf:bus>

    <jaxws:client name="{http://tempuri.org/}WSHttpBinding_IPersonService"
                  createdFromAPI="true">
        <jaxws:properties>
            <entry key="ws-security.username" value="Username"/>
            <entry key="ws-security.password" value="Password"/>
        </jaxws:properties>
    </jaxws:client>
</beans>
```

Answer (score 3):

CXF supports this kind of security policy. In fact it is currently tested, see here:

https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cxf.git;a=blob_plain;f=systests/ws-security/src/test/resources/wsdl_systest_wssec/wssc/WSSecureConversation_policy.wsdl;hb=1704fa3169b05c9e41e0c10b4c5cbd8ea83f1826

https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cxf.git;a=blob_plain;f=systests/ws-security/src/test/java/org/apache/cxf/systest/ws/wssc/WSSCTest.java;hb=1704fa3169b05c9e41e0c10b4c5cbd8ea83f1826

https://git-wip-us.apache.org/repos/asf?p=cxf.git;a=blob_plain;f=systests/ws-security/src/test/resources/org/apache/cxf/systest/ws/wssc/client.xml;hb=1704fa3169b05c9e41e0c10b4c5cbd8ea83f1826

Rather than using "ws-security.username" and "ws-security.password" with CXF, you need to use "ws-security.username.sct" and "ws-security.password.sct". This specifies to use these values for the bootstrap policy.

Answer (score 1):

I used Glassfish Metro and Netbeans to consume a similar service. There is a good guide here:
https://metro.java.net/1.5/guide/Creating_a_Client_to_Consume_a_WSIT_Enabled_Web_Service.html

After creating the web service client you can see it in Web Service References folder, right click on it and select "Edit Web Service Attributes...". In the popup you can enter your login details.

In the servlet you can use the code you wrote for accessing Person.

Comment: Thanks, but that didn't work, I'm getting the same error that "the message contains an invalid or expired security context token"